# Javascript world map that runs locally without internet access?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm challenged into finding a tool to use here.

The goal is to have a basic map where data can be put into, and each country can scale as a factor - exactly like Google's example [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart), that being the very first example: Region geochart.

However, it requires internet access as written [in the faq](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/faq). I checked out Leaflet as well - same story unfortunately!

My question is therefore if there are any Javascript world maps for offline use, similar to the geocharts from Google above?

Low resolution solutions would be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually using **LeafletJS** may be good way for offline maps also. You just need to get your **data from local source**, e.g. **geojson** or **svg**. For creating offline maps you can download and use LeafletJS library locally.

For a worldmap - example in codepen: http://codepen.io/dagmara223/pen/jydMqy

Copy script from example and save it to your local `html` file. Also please remember to download sources from
https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/ and update paths in your local file.
GeoJSON is put in one js codeblock with map functions but it would be better to put it in file aside and then add the path to that file in your script.

There are more tools and options to display geojson and svg data as worldmap, just look them up.

Another option for more advanced user - from LeafletJS you can also **call tiles stored locally** simply by:

```
L.tileLayer('{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
...
}).addTo(map);
```

But of course you have to have them stored locally in properly structured directories.